# Touchable elements like Buttons,TouchableHighlight etc not working within FlatList

Tags: react-native, react-native-flatlist

Touchable elements within a FlatList do not register touches. Why is the following code not working? Any help is appreciated. Thankyou.

```
_listener = () => {
    Alert.alert('Touched');
}

renderItem({item, index}){
    return<View>
      <Button
          title = "Button"
          color = "#ccc"
          onPress={this._listener}
      />
    </View>
}
```

Comment: 1.Have you bind the function '_listener' ?
2. Can you console log  onPress instead of calling a function, check if its working

Answer (score 0):

If you add extraData={this.state} within the flatlist you can get it to register touches.

Answer (score 0):

You need to bind your function, so you would have something like this:

```
  <Button
   title = "Button"
   color = "#ccc"
   onPress={this._listener.bind(this)}
   />
```